# Creating multifuntional Stored procedure using bit argument

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dapper

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [GetSubscriptions]
@id uniqueidentifier,
@isActive bit
AS
BEGIN
SELECT 
*
FROM SUBSCRIPTION
WHERE id=@id and IsActive= @isActive 
END
GO
```

I want to use it in this way-

1. when @isActive =1, it will return active subscription rows. -it works
2. when @isActive =0, it will return inactive subscription rows. -it works
3. Indepedent of IsActive Fiag, it will return all subscription rows -?

Subscription table has only two values for IsActive that is 0 and 1.
What would be the best short way so that it works for all these three conditions?Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

`@isActive` can have three states: 0, 1, or NULL.
Just add something for NULL to your where clause:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [GetSubscriptions]
@id uniqueidentifier,
@isActive bit
AS
BEGIN
SELECT 
*
FROM SUBSCRIPTION
WHERE id=@id and (IsActive= @isActive or @isActive is NULL)
END
GO
```

The two sides of the `or` can never be true at the same time, since comparing vs `NULL` using `=` is always false.  If `@isActive` is NULL, the `or` is True regardless of the value of the `isActive` column in `Subscription`.

Comment: Thanks but Subscription table has only two values for IsActive that is 0 and 1.

Comment: Yes, of course.  You asked how to return all rows of the subscription table, and the simplest change to your sproc is to pass in @isActive as NULL, and if so, don't care what the column value is.